# c++ A Generic Callback object implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, actionscript-3, flash, boost

**EDIT**: I've rewote this question in: [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66329804/3234641)

I'm currently using an implementation of callback mechanism from flash for c++, ASInterface.inl you can see an example here:

https://github.com/cpzhang/bud/blob/a37348b77fb2722c73d972a77827056b0b2344f6/trunk/tool/flash/ASInterface.inl#L393.

I'm looking for a standard implementation for generic callback like that (in std or in boost or something else), that is not coupled with flash player.
What it does basically is to implement a generic Callback object that can be called with arbitrary number of arguments of primitive types.

```
//init callbacks
typedef std::map<std::wstring, Callback> callbacks;
void SomethingHappened(int a, int b) {print a + b;}
string functionName = "SomethingHappened";
callbacks[functionName] = &SomethingHappened;
//use callbacks after xml input arrived:
string xml = "<some xml input document/>";
Callbacks::iterator itCallback = callbacks.find(functionName);
if (itCallback != callbacks.end())
    {
        //parse arguments
        std::vector<std::wstring> args;
        _Args::split(xml, args);
        ASValue::Array arguments;
        for (size_t i = 0, s = args.size(); i < s; ++i)
        {
            ASValue arg; arg.FromXML(args[i]);
            arguments.push_back(arg);
        }
        ASValue returnValue;
        //***this is where the magic happens: call the function***
        HRESULT result = itCallback->second.Call(arguments, returnValue);
        return result;
    }
```

*edit* this is my flow:
I get input message from "server": Message(String command, String xmlArguments)
it find the callback named: command
it invokes command with arguments (which are arbitrary in number and types).
What I'm looking is the implementation of the generic command (as there is in the link.)

Comment: What is `xmlArguments`? Is it an xml document that the arguments are going to be parsed from? Why not parse it to `ASValue::Array` as the given implementation did? I still don't see any function that needs invoking with other call signature

Comment: @sehe I wanted to make the code simpler, I'm getting an xml from server that has the function name and arguments.

Comment: @sehe: I've reposted the question, hope now is more clear: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66329804/3234641

Answer (score 0):

I didn't closely inspect all the nooks and crannies of that code, but is there something against this:

```
 using Callback = std::function<ASValue(ASValue::Array const&)>;
```

`std::function` is in C++ since c++11. If you don't have that (?) you can use `boost::function<>` with the same semantics.

Comment: yes but correct me if I wrong, here you call a function that gets an Array as a parameter, rather than arbitrary arglist? I want to support existing functions in my code that gets arguments like foo(int a,int b) and not foo(array values), and than parse the values

Comment: @AssafShouval that's what your code does right? I don't see any other function call in your code.

Comment: I want to support existing functions in my code that gets arguments like foo(int a,int b) and not foo(array values), and than parse the values

Comment: Which directiion? Can you clarify the question so that it is clear what you'd want to write?

Comment: thanks, I've edited my question and explained the flow in the end