# C++ generic callback implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, flash, boost

I have a code that takes messages from flash player in a form of XML parse them into function and arguments and calls a registered callback for that function.
The piece of code that I want to replace is something nicely done (almost) generic Callback mechanism:
[code for the generic callback implementation of flashSDK (ASInterface.inl)](https://github.com/cpzhang/bud/blob/a37348b77fb2722c73d972a77827056b0b2344f6/trunk/tool/flash/ASInterface.inl#L393).

The problem with it is that this code is written for flash and I want to replace the flash and use other service that will have the same interface. Is there any standard implementation of this callback mechanism (std? boost? something else open sourced?)?

This code implements generic callbacks mechanism that you can register function with number of arguments and types in a map:

```
void SomethingHappened(int a, int b) {print a + b;}
void SomethingElseHappened(string abcd) {print abcd;}
callbacks["SomethingHappened"] = &SomethingHappened;
callbacks["SomethingElseHappened"] = &SomethingElseHappened;
```

and than search for it and call with an array of arguments:

```
Callbacks::iterator itCallback = callbacks.find(functionName);
if (itCallback != callbacks.end())
{
    HRESULT result = itCallback->second.Call(arguments, returnValue);
}
```

full usage example:

```
//init callbacks
std::map<std::wstring, Callback> callbacks;
void SomethingHappened(int a, int b) {print a + b;}
void SomethingElseHappened(string abcd) {print abcd;}
callbacks[functionName] = &SomethingHappened;

void MessageArrived(string xmlInput)
{
    string functionName = parseFunctionName(xmlInput);
    Callbacks::iterator itCallback = callbacks.find(functionName);
    if (itCallback != callbacks.end())
    {
        //parse arguments
        std::vector<std::wstring> args;
        _Args::split(xml, args);
        ASValue::Array arguments;
        for (size_t i = 0, s = args.size(); i < s; ++i)
        {
            ASValue arg; arg.FromXML(args[i]);
            arguments.push_back(arg);
        }
        ASValue returnValue;
        //***this is where the magic happens: call the function***
        HRESULT result = itCallback->second.Call(arguments, returnValue);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you want `std::function<HRESULT(ASValue::Array, ASValue&)>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 no, because I have already the functions: SomethingHappened, SomethingElseHappened and many more, that has different declerations

Comment: You need a wrapper to create that `std::function`, no?

Comment: What is `ASValue`? some kind of `std::variant<int, string, double, ASValue::Array, ...>`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with std::variant. Though ASValue holds basic type data. see in this link:
 https://github.com/cpzhang/bud/blob/a37348b77fb2722c73d972a77827056b0b2344f6/trunk/tool/flash/ASInterface.inl#L32

Answer (score 2):

You probably need a wrapper around `std::function`, something like:

```
template <typename T> struct Tag{};

// Convert ASValue to expected type,
// Possibly throw for invalid arguments.
bool Convert(Tag<Bool>, AsValue val) { return (Boolean)val; }
int Convert(Tag<int>, AsValue val) { return (Number)val; }
// ...

struct Callback
{
private:
    template <std::size_t ... Is, typename Ret, typename ... Ts>
    static Ret call_impl(Ret(* func)(Ts...), std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        if (arr.size() != sizeof...(Is)) throw std::invalid_argument{};
        return func(Convert(tag<Ts>{}, arr[Is])...);
    }
public:
    template <typename Ret, typename ... Ts>
    Callback(Ret(* func)(Ts...)) : Call{[func](ASValue::Array arr, ASValue& ret)
        {
            try
            {
                ret = Callback::call_impl(func, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof(...(Ts)>());
                return S_OK;
            } catch (...) {
                return E_INVALIDARG;
            }
        }}
    {}

    std::function<HRESULT(ASValue::Array, ASValue&)> Call;
};
```

`std::index_sequence` is C++14, but you might find implementation on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement something like that.
A map of objects (GenericCallback here) containing `std::function<R(Args...)>` objects type-erased with `std::any` or `std::variant`.

**You need to be careful in the way you call your function callbacks though.**

E.g. I have to feed it a `std::string("hello world")` and not a simple C-string, otherwise the `std::any_cast` will throw (since a `function<string(const char*)>` is not a `function<string(string)>`).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <any>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

struct Caller {
    virtual ~Caller() = default;
    virtual std::any call(const std::vector<std::any>& args) = 0;
};


template<typename R, typename... A>
struct Caller_: Caller {

    template <size_t... Is>
    auto make_tuple_impl(const std::vector<std::any>& anyArgs, std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
        return std::make_tuple(std::any_cast<std::decay_t<decltype(std::get<Is>(args))>>(anyArgs.at(Is))...);
    }

    template <size_t N>
    auto make_tuple(const std::vector<std::any>& anyArgs) {
        return make_tuple_impl(anyArgs, std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
    }

    std::any call(const std::vector<std::any>& anyArgs) override {
        args = make_tuple<sizeof...(A)>(anyArgs);
        ret = std::apply(func, args);
        return {ret};
    };

    Caller_(std::function<R(A...)>& func_)
    : func(func_)
    {}

    std::function<R(A...)>& func;
    std::tuple<A...> args;
    R ret;
};

struct GenericCallback {

    template <class R, class... A>
    GenericCallback& operator=(std::function<R(A...)>&& func_) {
        func = std::move(func_);
        caller = std::make_unique<Caller_<R, A...>>(std::any_cast<std::function<R(A...)>&>(func));
        return *this;
    }

    template <class Func>
    GenericCallback& operator=(Func&& func_) {
        return *this = std::function(std::forward<Func>(func_));
    }

    std::any callAny(const std::vector<std::any>& args) {
        return caller->call(args);
    }

    template <class R, class... Args>
    R call(Args&&... args) {
        auto& f = std::any_cast<std::function<R(Args...)>&>(func);
        return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    std::any func;
    std::unique_ptr<Caller> caller;
};

using namespace std;

//Global functions
int sub(int a, int b) { return a - b; }
std::function mul = [](int a, int b) { return a*b;};
std::string sortString(std::string str) { 
    std::sort(str.begin(), str.end()); 
    return str;  
}

int main() 
{
    std::map<std::string, GenericCallback> callbacks;

    // Adding our callbacks

    callbacks["add"] = [](int a, int b) { return a + b; };
    callbacks["sub"] = sub;
    callbacks["mul"] = std::move(mul);
    callbacks["sortStr"] = sortString;

    // Calling them (hardcoded params)

    std::cout << callbacks["add"].call<int>(2, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << callbacks["sub"].call<int>(4, 2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << callbacks["mul"].call<int>(5, 6) << std::endl;
    std::cout << callbacks["sortStr"].call<std::string>(std::string("hello world")) << std::endl;

    // Calling "add" (vector of any params)

    std::vector<std::any> args = { {1}, {2} };
    std::any result = callbacks["add"].callAny(args);

    std::cout << "result=" << std::any_cast<int>(result) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/h63job

Comment: but in your calls you're hardcoding it's interface callbacks["add"].call<int>(2, 3), where what I need is to pass an arbitrary number of arguments to callback[function].call(args), and it will map the parameter by it's own

Comment: If you don't know at compile-time what's the type behind `args` (which means you intend it to be a `vector<any>` or something like that?) then there will be some extra work to do on your argument pack, yes. Like checking their type with `std::holds_alternative<T>(anyVar)`, casting them with `std::anyCast<T&>(anyVar)` and passing them to your registered function.

Comment: I do know in compile time the type behind arg, but the usage of callbacks[str].call should be done in the same way for sortStr and any other function signature... take a look at this code: https://github.com/cpzhang/bud/blob/a37348b77fb2722c73d972a77827056b0b2344f6/trunk/tool/flash/ASInterface.inl#L789

Comment: It looks like all their callback signatures are all the same: `std::any func(std::vector<std::any> args, std::any)`, or an equivalent with their variant type `ASValue`. This makes their job a lot easier, but that's not what you asked in your original question. You wanted to register things like `void SomethingHappened(int a, int b) {print a + b;}`.

Comment: no, look at how to addCallback. you can add SomethingHappened(int a, int b), by: GetASInterface()->AddCallback(L"SomethingHappened", &SomethingHappened); https://github.com/cpzhang/bud/blob/a37348b77fb2722c73d972a77827056b0b2344f6/trunk/tool/flash/ASInterface.inl#L866

Comment: Alright, this version makes it possible take a `vector<any>` as a unique argument: https://godbolt.org/z/h63job

Comment: Notice that `std::any`/`std::variant` are C++17, whereas OP tag C++11. (so have to use `boost::any` instead or equivalent).

Comment: can you eleborate on this: "You need to be careful in the way you call your function callbacks though."? how to be careful exactly?

Comment: @AssafShouval See this line? `std::cout << callbacks["sortStr"].call<std::string>(std::string("hello world")) << std::endl;` If I simply had given "hello world" as an argument, it would have looked for a callback with this signature explicitly: `std::string(*)(const char*)`, which isn't `sortString`'s type.

Comment: @AssafShouval There's some work to do inside the call/callAny methods when the std::any_cast fails. Maybe print an error and either abort or ignore the call. Maybe make a conversion table and implement those implicit param conversions yourself. Maybe restrain the callback registration to a small, manageable subset of types. That's up to you. Weak typing has its share of problems, and I've just given you a draft with little to no error checking.