# How to get a generic callback function or method with any types of return or parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm making some API and want to allow app developers to put their own callback function with any return types and any number of parameters. Below code is example I expect to work. I wonder how to define `?<?> userfunc` in `MyAPI.h`

```
// MyAPI.h

using namespace API {
/**
* Executes callback function after a random time in its own thread.
* @param userfunc User defined callback function.
**/
void SetCallback(?<?> userfunc);
}
```

```
// application.cpp

#include "MyAPI.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

std::string get_current_datetime() {
  const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  return std::format("{:%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%OS}", now);
}

bool callback_1(bool* triggered, std::string* registration_time) {
  *triggered = true;
  std::cout << "CALLBACK_1" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "registered: " << registration_time << std::endl;
  std::Cout << "triggered : " << get_current_datetime() << std::endl;
  return true;
}

int callback_2(int* triggered) {
  *triggered = 1;
  std::cout << "CALLBACK_2" << std::endl;
  return 1;
}

int main(void) {
  bool is_triggered_bool = false;
  int is_triggered_int = 0;
  std::string curr = get_current_datetime();
  API::SetCallback(std::bind(&callback_1, &is_triggered_bool, &curr));
  API::SetCallback(std::bind(&callback_2, &is_triggered_int))
  Sleep(3000);
  if (is_triggered_bool && is_triggered_int == 1) return 0;
  else return -1;
}
```

Any advice will appreciate

Comment: You can use template and std::function. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66329804/c-generic-callback-implementation)

Comment: Be careful with lambdas. If your API is, for example, accessed via a Windows DLL then you typically need to prevent allocations from operating across DLL boundaries. Because of the way lambda capture works, you might easily violate the rules. The typical way to do callbacks in C++ APIs is to provide an abstract class which the caller implements and then gives you a pointer to an instance. Alternatively, you can go old-school by using straight function pointers plus an additional "data" or "context" parameter that is a courtesy provided by the API to allow the plugin to do whatever they want.

Comment: How would your API call a function with an unknown return type? (Spoiler alert, it cannot).

Comment: What are you doing with the return value?  How are you (your code, not theirs) providing the arguments to the function?  Where does the data for those arguments come from?  How does the user (provider of the callback) specify what data goes in what arguments?  When do you call the callbacks, what causes it?